# pandas Series addition when indexed by floats is returning NaNs

Tags: python, pandas, series

I'm trying to work with series that are indexed by floats.
The goal is to manipulate time series without using datetime because this is for generic time as a non decreasing indexation and not for "human calendar times".

When I try to add two Series indexed by floats, I get all the values replaced with NaNs.
Is this expected, am I assuming something about the object that I should not?

I believe I'm in version 1.3.0.

```
import pandas as pd

seriesA = pd.Series([0.0, 1.2], index=[0.0, 8.92])
seriesB = pd.Series([-3.34, 2.7], index=[0.5, 0.8])
```

And then on the console:

```
>>> seriesA + seriesB
0.00   NaN
0.50   NaN
0.80   NaN
8.92   NaN
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the two series have no common index values, the output is indeed NaN.

You could use the `add` method so you could pass `fill_value` parameter.

```
seriesA.add(seriesB, fill_value=0)
```

Then you would have the expected output.

Comment: Thanks, is this because pandas tries to sum the values existing on one of the series with None and those are not operable together like that?

Comment: You are correct @Tom `NaN` in any computation is terminal. `NaN + any number = NaN`. In order to join the two series the index alignment introduces NaN values where they do not overlap. (And in this case that's every row)